# How can I use Mage.php in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7

In magento 1 if i use the code below file (ex Product) in model directory

```
<?php

class Crowderia_Demo_Model_Product {

    public function say() {
        echo "Testing";
    }
}
```

If i use test.php file in project directory I can get the method using mage.php file like below

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$product = new Product;
$product->say();
```

> How can I do this in magento 2

Please help me I'm new to magento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

try {
      $objectManager->create('Crowderia\Demo\Model\Product');
      $objectManager->say();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();       
}
```

**------ I have tested below code and it is working fine for me. Please try to update it by your own module. ------**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$quote = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');   
//I have created say fucntion under Product.php file
echo '<pre>';
print_r($quote->say());
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Crowderia\Demo\Model\Product)' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test.php on line 14

Comment: @Hemal Please see updated answer.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot declare class Product, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Crowderia\Demo\Model\Product.php on line 3

Comment: Add  `namespace Crowderia\Demo\Model;` in top of the file _app\code\Crowderia\Demo\Model\Produc‌​t.php_

Comment: Thanks for the help now it says    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::say() in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test.php on line 14

Comment: @Hemal Please see update answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
try {
    $obj->create('Crowderia\Demo\Model\Product);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Crowderia\Demo\Model\Product)' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test.php on line 14

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bootstrap.php` here. refer below example:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Your Class');
```

Comment: How can i get the method

Answer (score 1):

Please create an external file in Magento root directory.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require 'app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend'); // adminhtml

    // $bootstrap->run($app);
```